# Linking to a specific developer's App list on iTunes from within an iOS app?

Tags: list, search, hyperlink, directory, itunes

I would like to have a link in my iOS application that when clicked would open iTunes and point to a list of all applications of a specific developer.

I have tried using the iTunes link maker but i get the following error when accesing the link from the App:

> *Your request could not be completed. The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store.*

Say, I wanted to link to developer Yahoo!'s App page. Link Maker generates the following link:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/yahoo!/id281970157?mt=8&uo=4

However, the error message I mentioned pops up when clicked in my application.

Any advice?